# Selecting a dynamically created table row in ASP.NET with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamically-generated

I am writing a web application in Visual Studio 2015 pro using C# and ASP.NET. Right now, I have it set up where the user will click a button and the C# code will go get a bunch of data then display it back to the user in tables. I have spent a day of work trying to figure out how to add some form of a clickable event to the table rows but have had no success. Ultimately, what I want to do is call a method in my C# code when the table row is clicked and send it the row index.

Here is the C# code I am using for generating the tables:

```
    protected void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Remove the error display
            resultListLabel.Style.Add("Display", "None");

            // Get document groups 
            groups = TableCommands.getGroups(dbConn, "retriever", searchTextOne.Text, searchTextTwo.Text);

            foreach (var dataPair in groups)
            {                    
                // Get data pair group names into list
                List<string> name = dataPair.Key.Split('|').ToList();

                // ====== Make table
                Table resultTable = new Table();
                resultTable.Attributes["class"] = "displayTable";
                resultList.Controls.Add(resultTable);

                // ====== Add table info row
                TableRow groupInfo = new TableRow();
                groupInfo.Attributes["class"] = "groupInfoLabel";

                // add row to table
                resultTable.Rows.Add(groupInfo);                    

                // create cell with information
                TableCell infoCell = new TableCell();
                infoCell.Text = "MRN: "+name[0]+", Name: " + name[1];
                infoCell.ColumnSpan = 3;

                // add cell to row
                groupInfo.Cells.Add(infoCell);

                // ====== Make column label row
                TableRow labelRow = new TableRow();
                labelRow.Attributes["class"] = "columnLabel";

                // add row to table
                resultTable.Rows.Add(labelRow);

                // make an array of column lables
                string[] cellNames = new string[] { "Visit Date", "Document Type", "Doctor ID" };

                // add column lables to row
                foreach (string s in cellNames)
                {
                    TableCell labelCell = new TableCell();
                    labelCell.Text = s;
                    labelRow.Cells.Add(labelCell);
                }

                // Add display names to table
                foreach(var nameList in dataPair.Value)
                {
                    TableRow nameRow = new TableRow();
                    nameRow.Attributes["class"] = "columnInfo";


                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        TableCell nameCell = new TableCell();
                        nameCell.Text = nameList[i];
                        nameRow.Cells.Add(nameCell);
                    }
                    resultTable.Rows.Add(nameRow);
                }                    
            }       

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Display the error and write to log
            resultListLabel.Style.Add("Display", "Inline-Block");
            writeLog("Failed to generate tables", ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx

Comment: @AlexKrups - this for a `Table` not `DataGridView` and the link you sent was for WinForms not Asp.Net

Comment: You want to do it on the entire row and not simply add a button to a cell?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The row is all information pertaining to a single document. The rows that need to be clickable are the 'nameRow' s that are being added in the for loop at the end.

Comment: Is doing this with js and Ajax an option?

Comment: No, the code that I have to use to retrieve the document only works in c++ and c#. I looked at calling my c# methods with javascript but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: It can be done but you need some JavaScript here to handle on the OnClick event but unless I've misunderstood your question; essentially you're trying to reinvent the wheel as this is all handled (and more) with a `GridView`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I had to do:

1. Add a global boolean to called tableCall to the C# code
2. Move the code in searchButton_Click into an if(tableCall) statement in the Page_Load method.

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender ,EventArgs e){
       ...
       if(tableCall){
           //Do stuff from searchButton_Click
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Add tableCall = true; and Page_Load(sender, e) to searchButton_Click
4. Modify the for loop to add buttons in the cell like so:
           // Add display names to table
           foreach (var nameList in dataPair.Value)
           {
               TableRow nameRow = new TableRow();
               nameRow.Attributes["class"] = "columnInfo";

   ```
   // Add display names to table
   foreach (var nameList in dataPair.Value)
   {
       TableRow nameRow = new TableRow();
       nameRow.Attributes["class"] = "columnInfo";

       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           TableCell nameCell = new TableCell();
           nameRow.Cells.Add(nameCell);

           Button b = new Button();
           b.Attributes["class"] = "docButton";
           b.Attributes.Add("DWdocid", nameList[3]);
           b.Text = nameList[i];
           b.Click += new EventHandler((s, ea) => test(s, ea, b.Attributes["DWdocid"]));

           nameCell.Controls.Add(b);
       }
       resultTable.Rows.Add(nameRow);
   }
   ```

This adds a button to each of the three cells in the row, but adds the same document id to each of the buttons in that row, so anywhere the user clicks on that row (except for the 1px borders) will call a method in the C# code while passing it the document ID. I'm sure that with better css skills somebody could make the button span all three cells.

Comment: If you want it to span 3 cells, set the property `RowSpan = 3` so `nameCell.RowSpan = 3;`